# how do I eliminate the for-loop in this pytorch code

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I have this custom pytorch module (below). It does exactly what I need; it just does it very slowly. What can I do to speed this up? I know that I'm not supposed to have a for-loop in there; it just wasn't clear how to do that divide operation without it. How do I broadcast the x tensor to the divide without that loop? I can move the back-weights to their own layer if that helps.

```
class StepLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StepLayer, self).__init__()
        w = init_weights()
        self.front_weights = nn.Parameter(torch.DoubleTensor([w, w]).T, requires_grad=True)
        self.back_weights = nn.Parameter(torch.DoubleTensor([w]).T, requires_grad=True)
        

    def forward(self, x):
        # x shape is batch by feature
        results = []
        for batch in x:
            b = batch.divide(self.front_weights)
            b = torch.some_math_function(b)
            b = b.sum(dim=1)
            b = torch.some_other_math_function(b)
            b = b @ self.back_weights
            results.append(b)
        stack = torch.vstack(results)
        return stack
```

Comment: this depends on what your unspecified math functions do and whether they are broadcastable

Comment: The math functions are per-element. They're trigonometry and shouldn't need to broadcast.

Comment: and what about init-weights()?

Comment: The init_weights() method should be irrelevant. The weight vector size is correct already.

Comment: not irrelevant, what is the shape of w?

Comment: w is a single dimension; assume shape == (24,)

Comment: so x is BxF, front_weights is FxF and back_weights is F?

Comment: x is Bx2, front_weights is Fx2, back_weights is Fx1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a source code with shape after each step described (read code comments please).

I've assumed a few things like `F=100`, `x=Bx2`, `front_weights=100x2`, `back_weights=100`, you should be able to easily adjust it to your case.

```
class StepLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        F = 100
        # Notice I've added `1` dimension in front_weights
        self.front_weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, F, 2), requires_grad=True)
        self.back_weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(F), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        # x.shape == (B, 2)
        x = x.unsqueeze(dim=1)  # (B, 1, 2)
        x = x / self.front_weights  # (B, F, 2)
        # I just took some element-wise math function from PyTorch
        x = torch.sin(x)  # (B, F, 2)
        x = torch.sum(x, dim=-1)  # (B, F)
        x = torch.sin(x)  # (B, F)
        return x @ self.back_weights  # (B, )

        # results = []
        # for batch in x:
        #     # batch - (1, 2)
        #     b = batch.divide(self.front_weights)  # (F, 2)
        #     b = torch.some_math_function(b)  # (F, 2)
        #     b = b.sum(dim=1)  # (F, )
        #     b = torch.some_other_math_function(b)  # (F, )
        #     b = b @ self.back_weights  # (1, )
        #     results.append(b)
        # stack = torch.vstack(results)  # (B, )
        # return stack  # (B,)


layer = StepLayer()

print(layer(torch.randn(64, 2)).shape)
```

Main trick is to use `1` dimensions for broadcasting when necessary (division especially) and smart weight initialization so you don't have to do any transpose operations.

### Other things

- You might want to reconsider `Double`, `float` (as used above) is much faster, especially on CUDA and takes half the memory (and neural network should compensate for precision loss, if any).
- Use `half` precision and mixed training if the speed is still an issue (`float16` dtype instead of `float32`), **but only on CUDA**, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html#torch.cuda.amp.autocast) to know more about automated mixed precision

Comment: Yes, the `unsqueeze` is what I needed. As for double vs. float, my particular application requires at least 32 bits of mantissa, so I'm stuck with double-precision at the moment. I may do some further experimentation to see if I can do some mixed integer pieces.